# Changing state in store vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having issues setting a variable via ajax.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        conversationsList: []
    },
    mutations: {
        conversationList(state, payload) {
          state.conversationList = payload;
        }
    }
});

setInterval(function () {
    axios.get('/conversation/get-conversations')
        .then((response) => {
            store.commit('conversationList', response.data);
        });
}, 1000);
```

I cant understand why the state.conversationList = payload does not change the value?

Even replacing the ajax call with a simple array assignment such as

```
        var testList = [
            {id: 1, author:  'john', type: 'follower', lastMessage : 'hi'}
        ];

        store.commit('conversationList', testList);
```

doesnt work

Comment: Nah its not the typo, just typed it out wrong

Comment: Anyone see the difference between `conversationsList` and `conversationList`?

Comment: @EricGuan conversation**s**List :)

Comment: If it's not the typo, then this code is absolutely correct. Please provide the code that tries to access the store so we can see what went wrong.